# double subjunctive in conditional clause

Tags: grammar, conditionals

I came up with a question while reading a poem by Duhamel:

"If I were the kind who **made** promises, I'd probably begin by saying..."

So, why **made** and not "makes"? Is it strictly necessary to use the subjunctive form in that part of the sentence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There’s no subjunctive construction in your example. "Were" is irrealis mood, a very formal alternative to the modal preterite "was" (a tense form). It exhibits a high degree of modal remoteness, higher in fact than "was".

"Made" is a modal preterite, again used to denote modal remoteness, and replaceable by the non-modal present tense "makes"

Comment: There are no  modals here at all.

Comment: @Lambie I didn't say there were. I said **modal preterite**, which is the special use of the preterite (past) form of a verb to indicate modality rather than tense.

Comment: These forms were called the *"subjunctive"* fifty years ago, and still are quite often. Lots of people never received the memo about their renaming.

Comment: In the past, yes, it was claimed that /if I were/ was correct, and /If I was/ was not. Both are acceptable. Apart from that, constructions with IF are very clear. I don't think was is "modal preterite" and there is no modality in English. I'm gonna pass on this because it takes too much effort. If I were rich is the same construction as If they were poor. I shall leave it at that for now.

Comment: @Lambie Look: in _If I was the kind of person ..._, the verb "was" is a past tense form, but its meaning has nothing to with past time, but with modality by virtue of indicating a degree of remoteness or non-factuality. This remoteness is referred to as 'modality' and hence the verb is called a 'modal preterite'. Of course English has modality; the modal auxiliary verbs like "can", "may", "must", "will" etc are used to mark modality, hence their name!

Comment: Of course there are modals, but the verb to be is not one of them, in this case were.  A modal in the preterite would be: It may rain tomorrow. She said it might the next day. As to be is not a modal. were cannot be one.

Comment: @Lambie Okay, I'll try again: do you think that the "was" in _If I was the kind of person ..._ has to do with past time?

Comment: @ Lambie Please take a look at this link: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA46&lpg=PA46&dq=modal+preterite&source=bl&ots=WQGHc2djzZ&sig=cMv0Nxe-7AVZHPif2nP-vD8awI0&hl=en&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjd9sP5-vTKAhVGzRQKHdQ8C8AQ6AEIJjAB#v=onepage&q=modal%20preterite&f=false) Scroll down a tad, and you'll come to the section on modal preterites.

Comment: Thanks, @BillJ. Do you mind explaining why one should choose MADE (modal preterite) in my example and not the present form of the verb? That was the focus of my question, in fact. Could I use "makes" and still preserve meaning and grammatical accuracy? 
And what forms do you use to express "subjunctive mood," then? I can't tell the difference.

Comment: @M-b It has to do with ‘modality’: the use here of the modal preterite "made" presents your promise-making as a somewhat more remote possibility than present tense “makes”. You can use “makes” if you wish - it would be perfectly grammatical - but it would _very slightly_ weaken the overall modality, though the conditional “if” coupled with the highly modalised “were” (which has nothing to do with past time) would preserve the overall modal remoteness meaning. (Btw, I hope you found the link useful.)

Comment: @M-b A subjunctive clause is quite different. Unlike a modal preterite clause, which uses the **preterite**, (past tense) verb form, the subjunctive construction uses the **plain** (infinitve) form of the verb, as in _It is essential that I **be** kept informed_; _I insist that he **meet** her_, and such like. Incidentally, despite what schoolboy grammar books and websites may tell you, the "were" in _If I were you_, is **not** past-subjunctive. The "were" in that example is called 'irrealis' mood, a formal alternant to modal preterite "was".

Answer (score 1):

Interesting discussion here. I've noticed what I'll call "irrealis preterite modality", following BillJ's contribution. I think I should be clear about what he calls "remoteness", this is actually two separate things, one is "unreality" stemming from the use of what is commonly known as the irrealis mood. The other is "hypotheticality" stemming from the use of the past preterite verb form, and phenomena we're calling "preterite modality".

"Preterite modality" used by everyone when differentiating the 1st and 2nd conditionals in English. To illustrate this, "If I become president then I will lower taxes" sounds like what a politician would say, "If I became president then I would lower taxes" sounds like something anyone might say, regardless of their political ambition. If the outcome is a realistic possibility we use present tense form verbs in the conditional, if the outcome is hypothetical we use past tense form verbs (aka preterite verb forms). In this case these are become/became and will/would. Bear in mind that will/would are what are known as "modal verbs" so don't behave quite normally, however, don't think that modality is only to do with those verbs we call "modal verbs", because it's not. Anyway the important thing to remember is that "Preterite modality" stresses hypotheticality.

The "irrealis" mood is used in English to stress "unreality", essentially to cast doubt on a claim. It's sometimes referred to as the subjunctive but most modern grammarians think that it's incorrect to class it as subjunctive. What's crazy about the irrealis mood is that it only exists in one verb in the entire language, and that verb is "were". What's even more crazy is that it's only possible to even be aware of whether its usage by a speaker is intentional in the 1st and 3rd person singular. The irrealis is marked by the use of the verb form "were" instead of the verb form "was". For example, "If I were there, I would do it" (conditional) and "I wish she were here" (wish, desire), and "He said he were working" (casting doubt on a claim). To make things even more crazy this irrealis form is pretty much optional in much of the English speaking world. Anyway, the important thing to take away here is that the irrealis mood stressed that something is unreal, that what we're talking about isn't true.

Now what you've got in the example is a straight 2nd conditional, and the antecedent of a 2nd conditional a place where it's completely correct to use the irrealis if you want to. What's unusual about "If I were the kind who made promises, I'd probably begin by saying..." is that you've got a relative clause coming under the scope of an "if-clause". This give us the opportunity to create what I'm calling a "irrealis preterite modality", occurring when two finite verbs are falling under the scope of the antecedent of the conditional.

"If I **were** the kind who **made** promises"

Now if he'd said "If I **was** the kind who **made** promises", you'd simply have two preterite modalities, but because he used "were", you've got two preterite modalities and an irrealis ("were" being both a preterite modality and irrealis). And this is what I'm calling "irrealis preterite modality".

What's even crazier is that with the first verb of the example the irrealis is pretty much optional (both was or were are fine), and that in the second verb the preterite modality is pretty much optional (both makes and made are fine).

Thus:

If I were the kind who made promises 
If I was the kind who made promises
If I were the kind who makes promises 
If I was the kind who makes promises

Are all completely comprehensible English sentences with very little difference in meaning.

However, I think that opting to use the irrealis, and opting to use the preterite modality, have very similar functions, which is stressing unreality and hypotheticality, which are obvious concepts that occur together very often. I will also add that using preterite modality in the 2nd verb in this case also sounds more "proper" to me, merely because of tense agreement.

To answer OP's questions. You can basically just use either was/were or make/makes in your example and the meaning is pretty much identical, as in modern speech all are viable. The were + made example just stresses the unreality/hypotheticality most emphatically, and matching the tenses stylistically seems more formal.